# Message compatibility between app versions when using Android Realtime Multiplayer Gaming

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am trying to develop my first Android app with the Google Realtime Multiplayer Gaming API. This will involve sending update messages to the peers as the game progresses. I would expect that down the line, as I make updates to my game in subsequent versions, some of the data may change and I would like to keep the messaging compatible between app versions. This is a common problem in other fields like networking and usually solved using solutions like TLVs or Google Protobufs. What is the recommended way to handle this in Android apps? Also, when a peer-to-peer connection is formed (when player joins room), do we have any way of knowing that app version the peer is using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also dont have a satisfing answer for this. Currently i wouldnt match versions that differ in that regard. To prevent that, it should be possible to use the variant bitmask in the autoMatchCriteria and reserve some bits to identify the version.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I ended up using good old TLVs for this. During handshake one of the TLVs my app sends includes the app versioncode.